# How to disable FIDO authenticator?

Tags: ssh, authentication, two-factor-authentication

Whenever I run the command `ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa`, I get a prompt asking for the FIDO authenticator pin.

How do I disable the FIDO authenticator?

[image]

Comment: See https://serversuit.com/community/technical-tips/view/how-do-i-run-ssh-add-without-a-password.html

Answer (score 0):

I think its your -K argument

-K      Load resident keys from a FIDO authenticator.